# Faster way to find empty cells and Cells containing specific string in Excel 2013

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

While creating and customizing Excel file using Interop and Office 2013 installed, gives me somehow extremely slow results (more than 5 minutes).
In fact, the same thing works very well on Excel 2010 interop (just 50 seconds, exactly same process). (Code snippet below)

It would be nice to know if there is a faster way to do this. I know there are different libraries to do this but I would like to stick to Interop since everything is already in the same.
I am creating Excel file first then **check if there are any empty cells or cells containing a specific string and change color of those cells.
To create Excel, I used Object array and parse it that is really faster. Main thing which is pulling it down is to search and change cell color.**

```
// Check for empty cell and make interior silver color
for (int row = 0; row < rowNo; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < columnNo; col++)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objData[row, col].ToString()))
        {
            // Access that cell in Excel now and change interior color
            Range cell = (Range)activeSheet.Cells[row + 2, col + 1];
            cell.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Silver; 
        }
    }
}

// Check for cells contains "column header string#"
for (int col = 16; col < columnNo; col++)
{
    // Get column header - only once and use it for all rows in the same column
    string cellValue = activeSheet.Cells[1, col + 1].Value2.ToString();
    for (int row = 0; row < rowNo; row++)
    {
        string value = objData[row, col].ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Contains(cellValue+"#"))
        {
            Range cell = (Range)activeSheet.Cells[row + 2, col + 1];
            cell.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
            cell.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does objData come from?

Comment: @TheBlastOne: That one I created from DataTable, basically it is just an entire DataTable to object array. This I used to parse to Excel, resulted in a fastest way of writing DataTable to Excel.

Comment: You might look at the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` to get the blank cells in one range object. Should be easy to work with.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.specialcells(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: @David Zemens: That is an option for sure but what about if I want to look for cells containing specific strings, substring?
Besides, it gives an error every time even though there are empty cells in Excel, no idea why. I used `String.Empty` and `""` to write in Excel but doesn't seem to be working well.

Comment: for specific strings/substrings you can use the range `.Find` method, in a loop, or you can use `AutoFilter` method to filter the range to the criteria and then use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into selecting the whole range and setting conditional formatting so blank cells are the color you want. Sorry don't have any code for you, it's been awhile since I've played in that realm.

Comment: thanks, it's okay with code. In fact, I am more interested in Excel 2013 issue. Because this same code works very well and fast enough with Excel 2010. I have been testing on both systems and results are completely unacceptable on Excel 2013.
I want to know why, what's going on or what has been changed which is causing this problem.